# Are any websites currently using the following non-relational databases as backend? 1.SimpleDB 2.CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, backend, amazon-simpledb

I would also like to know if any sites have implemented any other non relational databases, and for what purpose..

Comment: Is there a programming question in there somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following list for Couch:

- http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/CouchDB_in_the_wild